# How to query blockchain bitcoin locally

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, blockchain

I downloaded 122 gb file of the complete blockchain to my computer with the download of the bitcoin core wallet. I would like to query against it locally using preferably node.js.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json RPC provided by bitcoin core.

You can call http calls via node.js.

see below.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Node.js

or there are other third party libraries.

https://bitcoinjs.org/

which are wrappers of above RPC calls.